# Windows: in batch file, write multiple lines to text file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

How can I do the following in a Windows batch file?

1. Write to a file called subdir/localsettings.py
2. Overwrite all existing content...
3. ...with multiple lines of text...
4. ...including a string that is "[current working directory]/subdir" (which I think might be `%cd%/subdir`?)

Please note, I want to do this as part of a batch script so I can't use `con` + Enter (at least, maybe I can, but I don't know how to simulate Enter as part of a batch script).

Thanks!

Answer (score 65):

Use output redirection `>` and `>>`

```
echo one>%file%
echo two>>%file%
echo three>>%file%
```

Or in a more readable way: (In `cmd.exe`, using "`echo one >%file%`" would include the whitespace before `>`.)

```
>%file%  echo one
>>%file% echo two
>>%file% echo three
```

You could also use:

```
(
    echo one
    echo two
    echo three
) >%file%
```

Comment: For blank lines, `echo.` or `echo=` or `echo:` or... (There are quite a few separators that `cmd.exe` recognizes; not only space. So far I've discovered `.;,/=+\` with `echo`)

Comment: The selected answer omits stderr - while it may not be necessary in this question, when redirecting output you should consider that if the command line app outputs errors to stderr,simply using > or >> to redirect output will not catch the errors.  You would need to use 2>&1 or 2>>&1 to redirect to the same file, or specify a different file.  For example: 
net /? >StdOutLog.txt 2>StdErrLog.txt
(the net command is a little odd in that it displays output to standard error - net subcommand displays to standard output, so net use >stdOutLog.txt 2>StdErrLog.txt will find data in stdOutLog.txt)

Comment: @grawity `echo.` and the most others can collide with an existing file "echo" and they always forces a file system access, `echo(` seems to be "safe"

Comment: @jeb: Good point. But I [tested](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) a few variations, and only `.,\:` cause the shell to check for a file of the same name in the current directory (_not_ entire `%PATH%`, though). The other possible separators `/=([]+` are all "safe".

Comment: @grawity: You are right, not all variants check for a file, but they are not "safe" against other "problems" like `/?` or `on`. Discussed here [echo. fails](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774&p=4554#p4554)

Comment: @jeb: Re-tested my "safe" list; `=` fails with `echo=/?`, but the rest work. (Regarding your forum post: With `/` you can use `echo//?`, not `echo/?`. For a single question mark, simple `echo ?`. But by now any sane person would have ported the script into another language (the asker already has Python installed). It's what I would do, anyway.)

Comment: @grawity: The problems only occours with `echo/!variable!`, it should work independent of the content of variable even if it is empty.

Answer (score 8):

```
echo Line 1^

Line 2^

Line 3 >textfile.txt
```

Note the double new-lines to force the output:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

Also:

```
(echo Line 1^

Line 2^

Line 3)>textfile.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

If you wann do it in 1 line, here a more complex example

- I simulate a carriage return with `\n`
- I escape special character for parenthesis
- I replace the `\n` with what is needed in batch

```bash
set text=Cols:\n- Port de Lers (1517m) avec le col d'Agnès (1570m)\n- Col de la Core (1395m)\n- Col de Menté (1349m)\n- Col de Peyresourde (1569m)\n- Col du Tourmalet (2115m)\n- Col d'Aubisque (1709m)\n- Col de Marie-Blanque (1035m)\n- Col de Labays (1354m)
set "text=%text:(=^(%" :: I escape special character for parenthesis
set "text=%text:)=^)%" :: I escape special character for parenthesis
set "text=%text:\n= >> temp.txt & echo %" :: I replace the `\n` with what is needed in batch 
set "text=%text:"=%"
if exist "temp.txt" rm temp.txt :: just remove the file if exist to avoid to append in it
echo %text% >> temp.txt
cat temp.txt :: print result
```

```
C:\ > cat temp.txt
Cols:
- Port de Lers (1517m) avec le col d'Agnès (1570m)
- Col de la Core (1395m)
- Col de Menté (1349m)
- Col de Peyresourde (1569m)
- Col du Tourmalet (2115m)
- Col d'Aubisque (1709m)
- Col de Marie-Blanque (1035m)
- Col de Labays (1354m)
```

If you wanna delete the last \r\n use `truncate -s -2 temp.txt`
Install `git` on windows to be able to use `truncate`